# Cannot delete Java Card applet

Tags: java, applet, javacard

I am quite new to Java Card but after some reading, my first Applet is working quite well.....until today. I refactored a bit and inserted an OwnerPIN object to my Applet. And now I can write the Applet once, but the second time, the deletion does not work anymore.
Here is my output:

```
Java Card 2.2.2 Class File Converter, Version 1.3
Copyright 2005 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
mode_201
gemXpressoPro
enable_timer
establish_context
command time: 16 ms
card_connect
command time: 187 ms
select -AID A000000018434D00
command time: 78 ms
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -key 47454d5850524553534f53414d504c45 -keyDerivation visa2
command time: 328 ms
delete -AID  0102030405060708090000
delete() returns 0x80206985 (6985: Command not allowed - Conditions of use not satisfied.)
command time: 31 ms
delete -AID  01020304050607080900
delete() returns 0x80206985 (6985: Command not allowed - Conditions of use not satisfied.)
command time: 47 ms
get_status -element e0


List of applets (AID state privileges)
a000000018434d00 1 9e
a0000000620001 1 0
a0000000620002 1 0
a0000000620003 1 0
a0000000620101 1 0
a000000062010101 1 0
a0000000620102 1 0
a0000000620201 1 0
a0000000620209 1 0
a0000000620202 1 0
a000000018100109 1 0
a00000001810010b 1 0
a00000001810010a 1 0
a0000000030000 1 0
a000000018100106 1 0
a000000018100201 1 0
a000000018100101 1 0
a00000015100 1 0
a000000018100108 1 0
a0000000181001ff 1 0
a000000018100501 1 0
a000000018100502 1 0
a000000018100401 1 0
5365637572697479 1 0
a0000000035350 1 0
01020304050607080900 1 0
0102030405060708090000 7 0
command time: 187 ms
install -file mycap.cap -sdAID A000000018434D00 -nvCodeLimit 4096 -instParam 2265
install_for_load() returns 0x80206985 (6985: Command not allowed - Conditions of use not satisfied.)
```

*update*
As requested, parts of my code:

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet
{

   private static final byte MY_CLA = (byte)0xB0;

  ...
    private final static byte VERIFY_INS = (byte)0x40;
 ...
    private final static byte NEED_VERIFICATION_INS = (byte)0x47;
    private final static byte GET_INSTALL_PARAMS_INS = (byte)0x50;
    private final static byte GET_REMAINING_PIN_TRIES_INS = (byte)0x60;

    private final static byte PIN_TRY_LIMIT = (byte)0x03;
    private final static byte MAX_PIN_SIZE = (byte)0x08;

    // signal that the PIN verification failed
    private final static short SW_VERIFICATION_FAILED = 0x6300;
    private final static short SW_PIN_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED = 0x6301;

   ...
    private static byte[] testdata;
    private OwnerPIN m_pin;
    private byte[] m_array;
    private short m_offset;
    private byte m_length;

    private MyApplet(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength)
    {
       ...
        m_pin = new OwnerPIN(PIN_TRY_LIMIT, MAX_PIN_SIZE);
        // m_array = bArray;
        // m_offset = bOffset;
        // m_length = bLength;
        register();
    }

    public boolean select()
    {
        if (m_pin.getTriesRemaining() == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void deselect()
    {
        m_pin.resetAndUnblock();
    }

    private void adminRest()
    {
        m_pin.resetAndUnblock();
        return;
    }


    private void getInstallParams(APDU apdu)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
            // inform the JCRE that the applet has data to return
            short le = apdu.setOutgoing();
            // set the actual number of the outgoing data bytes
            apdu.setOutgoingLength(((short)testdata.length));
            apdu.sendBytesLong(testdata, (short)0, (short)testdata.length);

        }
        catch (APDUException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (TransactionException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get number of remaining pin tries
     * 
     * @param apdu
     */
    private void getPinTriesRemaining(APDU apdu)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
            // inform the JCRE that the applet has data to return
            apdu.setOutgoing();
            // set the actual number of the outgoing data bytes
            apdu.setOutgoingLength((byte)2);

            // write the PinTriesRemaining into the APDU buffer at the offset 0
            Util.setShort(buffer, (short)0, m_pin.getTriesRemaining());

            // send the 2-byte balance at the offset
            // 0 in the apdu buffer
            apdu.sendBytes((short)0, (short)2);
        }
        catch (APDUException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (TransactionException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

    } // end of getPinTriesRemaining method

    /**
     * Verification method to verify the PIN
     * 
     * @param apdu
     */
    private void verify(APDU apdu)
    {

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        // receive the PIN data for validation.
        byte byteRead = (byte)(apdu.setIncomingAndReceive());

        // check pin
        // the PIN data is read into the APDU buffer
        // starting at the offset ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA
        // the PIN data length = byteRead
        if (!m_pin.check(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, byteRead))
        {
            ISOException.throwIt(SW_VERIFICATION_FAILED);
        }

    } // end of verify method

    /**
     * Installs the applet.
     *
     * @param bArray array with installation parameters.
     * @param bOffset offset into array.
     * @param bLength the length of the parameters.
     */
    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength)
    {
        testdata = new byte[bLength];
        Util.arrayCopy(bArray, (short)0, testdata, (short)0, bLength);
        new MyApplet(bArray, bOffset, bLength);
    }


    /**
     * Processes an incoming APDU.
     *
     * @param apdu the APDU.
     */
    public void process(APDU apdu)
    {

        byte l_transferredBuffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Get the CLA; mask out the logical-channel info.
        l_transferredBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] = (byte)(l_transferredBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & (byte)0xFC);
        if ((l_transferredBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == 0) && (l_transferredBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == (byte)(0xA4)))
        {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
        if (l_transferredBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != MY_CLA)
        {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        byte l_ins = l_transferredBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];

      ...
        else if (l_ins == VERIFY_INS)
        {
            verify(apdu);
        }
        ...
        else if (l_ins == NEED_VERIFICATION_INS)
        {
            isNeedVerification(apdu, l_transferredBuffer);
        }
        else if (l_ins == GET_INSTALL_PARAMS_INS)
        {
            getInstallParams(apdu);
        }
        else if (l_ins == GET_REMAINING_PIN_TRIES_INS)
        {
            getPinTriesRemaining(apdu);
        }
        else
        {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }

    private void isNeedVerification(APDU apdu, byte[] buffer)
    {
        // The structure for the response request is
        // ---------------------
        // | response |
        // | 1 byte |
        // ---------------------
        getRequest(apdu, buffer);
        byte[] l_needVerificationResponse = new byte[1];
        boolean l_validated = m_pin.isValidated();
        if (l_validated)
        {
            l_needVerificationResponse[0] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            l_needVerificationResponse[0] = 0;
        }
        apdu.setOutgoing();
        apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)l_needVerificationResponse.length);
        apdu.sendBytesLong(l_needVerificationResponse, (short)0, (short)l_needVerificationResponse.length);
    }

    private byte[] getRequest(APDU apdu, byte[] transferredBuffer)
    {
        short l_setIncomingAndReceive = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        byte[] request = new byte[l_setIncomingAndReceive];
        for (short i = 0; i < request.length; i++)
        {
            short l_j = (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + i);
            request[i] = transferredBuffer[l_j];
        }
        return request;
    }
... 
}
```

Is my card blocked? I can see that my AID runs in state 7...what does that mean. Is it connected to my OwnerPIN object?

Thanks for your help!
Jan

Comment: Where did you insert the OwnerPIN object to your  Applet? Show the code if convenient.

Comment: Hi,
sure - see the skeleton of my code in the OP. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: From the question I assume the package AID is `01020304050607080900` and instance AID is `0102030405060708090000`. Thus the deletion of the package fails as well. Are you sure this package is not referenced by some other applet/package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problematic line is this one:

```
private static byte[] testdata;
```

Remember, `static` references to persistent objects are **EVIL AND DANGEROUS**. They are always there, even after the `Applet` instance is uninstalled and garbage collected. That is why the referenced object (byte array in your case) is never garbage collected, the persistent memory is never released and thus the deletion command fails.

If you can avoid using `static` references, **do so**.

If you cannot avoid it, use `AppletEvent` interface:

```
public final class MyApplet extends Applet implements AppletEvent {

    private static byte[] testdata;
    ...

    //This method is called in the moment of uninstallation
    public final void uninstall() {
        testData = null; //release the reference --> testData can be GC
    }
    ...

}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, thx. Is there any possibility to recover the "blocked" cards?

Comment: @JanEngler There is no possibility, I am afraid. You could recover it if your testData was `public` (you could perhaps set it to null from another applet), but it is `private`...

Comment: damn ;) Thx a lot for your help! I will try the fix later (on another card... :) ).

Comment: @JanEngler you could change package and applet AID and test it on the same card...

Comment: Oh, good idea. One more question: why are lines like this unproblematic:
private final static byte MAX_PIN_SIZE = (byte)0x08; ?

Comment: @JanEngler Because it is a primitive type, not an object. No GC involved.

Comment: I am just curious...Should not be this field deleted during the deletion of the package (using _"Delete object and related object"_ -- which is the case of `gpshell`)? I see that the deletion of the package apparently fails, but I had some recent Gemalto cards where this worked...

Comment: Can't him delete the package completely? (using `gp.exe -delete PackAID -deletedeps` for instance).

Comment: `"Conditions of use not satisfied"` is related to the authentication keys I guess, and it is not related to the `static` variables. right?

Comment: @Abraham In this case there is no connection to authentication keys. It is really caused by not released persistent objects. `"Conditions of use not satisfied"` can mean a lot of things.

Comment: I am just installed the same applet that the questioner added to his post on my JCOP card and then I  deleted it and installed it successfully again and again with the same AIDs. I think when we delete a _package_, all of its objects (including the persistent ones) will release.

Comment: It's a JCOP V2.4.2 JavaCard.

Comment: Anyway, I tried the same process with a really old JavaCard (JC 2.2.1) and result is the same.

Comment: @Abraham Alright, my answer could be wrong... Try contacting the questioner and explain him what to do, please. He will decide if your solution works for him...

Answer (score 2):

I installed your applet on two different JavaCards and then I deleted it and installed it again and again successfully.

First of all please download the [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/releases) tool. (It's free and if you are working in Windows platform, then `gp.exe` is enough for your case.)

After downloading try these commands in the command-line:

**List you installed applets and their packages AID:**

```
G:\BasicTestTools\SmartCardTools>gp -key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected, CVM (PIN) management

AID: 010203040503 (|......|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

AID: 0102030405 (|.....|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     010203040503 (|......|)
```

Note that in the above output, those AIDs that are marked with `App`, are applets and those AIDs that are marked with `ExM` are *Executable Modules*(Packages).

The `0102030405` and `010203040503` in the results are Pack AID and App AID of your program in my card.

**Deleting the package by alone, without deleting its applet:**

If I try to delete the package without deleting its applet, then it fails and I receive the same error that you receive:

```
G:\BasicTestTools\SmartCardTools>gp -key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -delete 0102030405
Could not delete AID: 0102030405
TIP: Maybe try with --deletedeps
pro.javacard.gp.GPException: Deletion failed SW: 6985
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:1092)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.deleteAID(GlobalPlatform.java:867)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:390)
```

There are two ways to delete it:

1. Delete the applet first and then delete the packages.
2. Delete the package with all of its dependencies(including the applet).

**Deleting the package and the applet simultaneously:**

I choose the second solution (a parameter `-deletedeps` added to the delete command):

```
G:\BasicTestTools\SmartCardTools>gp -key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -delete 0102030405 -deletedeps

G:\BasicTestTools\SmartCardTools>gp -key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected, CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)
```

**Installing the same applet with the same AIDs for the Package and the Applet again:**

As you see, your package and the applet are deleted. Now I install it again:

```
G:\BasicTestTools\SmartCardTools>gp -key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -install C:\NetBeansProjects\test2\dist\test2.cap

G:\BasicTestTools\SmartCardTools>gp -key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected, CVM (PIN) management

AID: 010203040503 (|......|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

AID: 0102030405 (|.....|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     010203040503 (|......|)
```

Well, As you see the applet installed successfully again.

**Note that you must replace my card's authentication keys with your card's authentication keys(I mean replace `404142...4f` with your card's keys)**

Anyway, if in the first step (Listing installed applets) you faced with the `0x6985` error, that means your keys are not correct. For example if I put a random number for the `key` parameter in the command the I will face this result:

```
G:\BasicTestTools\SmartCardTools>gp -key 00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff -list
pro.javacard.gp.GPException: STRICT WARNING: Card cryptogram invalid!
Card: 7F9CFF3D61110EF2
Host: 9EE2CDBF4A088053
!!! DO NOT RE-TRY THE SAME COMMAND/KEYS OR YOU MAY BRICK YOUR CARD !!!
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.printStrictWarning(GlobalPlatform.java:184)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.openSecureChannel(GlobalPlatform.java:515)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:371)
```

And as it indicate in the output, you have limited tries for the value of `key`. Typically after 10 wrong tries, your card will be locked and the lock life cycle is irreversible.

Comment: The strange thing is, that this approach probably will not work for the OP, as `gpshell` uses the _delete object and related object_ (i.e. `P2=0x80`) by default (at least my slightly tweaked version 1.4.5 built from SVN). And it did not work according the log given by the OP (assuming AIDs as written in my comment).

Comment: @vlp Well, so that's weird! There are for posibilities: **1-** Mr Vojta's answer is correct and my cards have an addition feature that let me delete and install this applet without any trouble. **2-** The version of `GPShell` that the  questioner used is old and doesn't delete the objects by default. **3-** The questioner's card is locked or the keys that he/she use is not correct (and the card is not locked yet.). 4- You are not right about the `GPShell` or it doesn't work as we expected. :)

Comment: You are right, maybe the OP could enable command trace in `gpshell` using `enable_trace` and check the `P2` value. The card keys are probably OK, because the script would fail in the `opensc` otherwise...

Comment: I'm cleaning up my java card applets. How can I know which applets were mine? I did lots of experimentation installing etc. I like to delete some, but i am worried if i delete a critical system applet and will malfunction my card. Any tips?